# Can I change parameter of plugins in yaml

Tags: ros, yaml

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have installed range_sensor_layer for local_costmap.
in the local_costmap_param.yaml:

```
local_costmap:
  global_frame: /odom
  robot_base_frame: /base_footprint
  update_frequency: 3.0
  publish_frequency: 1.0
  static_map: false
  rolling_window: true
  width: 6.0
  height: 6.0
  resolution: 0.05
  transform_tolerance: 1.0
  map_type: costmap
  plugins:
     - {name: sonar,   type: "range_sensor_layer::RangeSensorLayer"}
```

### the range_sensor_layer has some parameters,is it possible to change them in this yaml?

I found some code in costmap_2d_ros.cpp line 114:

```
if (private_nh.hasParam("plugins"))
{
  XmlRpc::XmlRpcValue my_list;
  private_nh.getParam("plugins", my_list);
  for (int32_t i = 0; i < my_list.size(); ++i)
  {
    std::string pname = static_cast<std::string>(my_list[i]["name"]);
    std::string type = static_cast<std::string>(my_list[i]["type"]);
    ROS_INFO("Using plugin \"%s\"", pname.c_str());

    boost::shared_ptr<Layer> plugin = plugin_loader_.createInstance(type);
    layered_costmap_->addPlugin(plugin);
    plugin->initialize(layered_costmap_, name + "/" + pname, &tf_);
  }
}
```

It looks like should be:

```
......
plugins:
     - {name: sonar,   type: "range_sensor_layer::RangeSensorLayer"}
sonar:
     ......
     ......
```

but my sonar on the way,I cannot test this.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/276535/can-i-change-parameter-of-plugins-in-yaml/) by [dyan](https://answers.ros.org/users/29703/dyan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2017-11-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2017-11-28**:
Yup. This is the way to do it...

**Comment by [dyan](https://answers.ros.org/users/29703/dyan/) on 2017-11-30**:
@mig: thanks for confirm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yup. This is the way to do it...

(So you can acutally mark this as answered...)

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2017-11-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0